# When calling sendMail, how do I get the error if the mail isn't sent?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, emails, error-handling

I'm sending email using the following code:

```
$mail =& JFactory::getMailer();
$email_sent = $mail->sendMail( 
        $from_email,
        $from_name,
        $to_email,
        $subject,
        $email_body,
        $sendas,
        $cc_emails,
        $bcc_emails,
        $email_attachments,
        $reply_to_email,
        $reply_to_name );
if($email_sent) {
    echo "Mail sent.";
} else {
    echo "Mail NOT sent.";
}
```

All of the variables are set to the appropriate values.

When $email_sent is false, is there a way to capture the error message or another way to find out why the email wasn't sent?

I'm on Joomla 3.7 and php 5.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, just on a side note, please remove the `&` before `JFactory`

There was a pull request submitted on Github a year ago that allowed Joomla to catch the errors being throw by PHPMailer:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/9881

I'm not sure at the implementation but according to the documentation, the `send()` function will return a `JError` object if any errors occurred:

https://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions

Comment: Thanks for the info. Seems like everything I could find was for previous versions of Joomla. I switched to send from sendMail (and removed the "&"), and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

None of the proposed solutions work. The jMailer `return` value is a headache because you can't catch exceptions or even know the type of the `send()` return.

If success returns a boolean `true`; if not it returns a Jexception object, the two outcomes loosely evaluate as boolean true values!

The simplest way I found is:

```
$result = $mail->Send();
if ($result === true)  return true;
else  return false;
```

Comment: The second link in the accepted answer (to the Joomla docs) shows how to perform a strict check on the result with `$send = $mailer->Send();
if ( $send !== true ) {`  This is just reversing the design of the condition block that you have posted, but effectively the same logic is already provided by the Joomla -- very clearly too.  You must have misunderstood the implementation when you tried.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the error using a conditional statement, like so:

```
if (!$send)
{
    $error = $send->__toString();
}
```